# Friendbot request fails with 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: horizon, accounts, stellar-sdk

I am trying to create an account on the stellar Test Network. I am using ASP .Net framework. But whenever I make a request and pass in the public key, I always get this error:

`Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)`.

I'll add that I am using the Javascript documentation from [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html)
and converting it to C# code because I didn't find any documentation for C#. Is there anything I'm missing out?

this is how the code looks:

```
try {
  string url = "https://friendbot.stellar.org?addr=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.PublicKey);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);    
  string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
  object responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseBody);
  return Ok(responseObject);
} catch(Exception ex) {
  return BadRequest("Could not Establish a successful connection with Stellar because " + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got it to work. Switched from using the public key to using the address.

```
 try
    {
       KeyPair pair = KeyPair.Random();

       string url = "https://friendbot.stellar.org?addr=" + pair.Address;
       string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
       object responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseBody);
       return Ok(responseObject);
    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
          return BadRequest("Could not Establish a connection with Stellar because " + ex.Message);
        }
```